# How to debug iOS react-native app when using visual studio?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code, react-native-ios

I have recently started working on an iOS app that uses react-native. I'm using Visual Studio Code for writing javascript/typescript code. I would like to debug javascript and swift code in parallel.

I have tried using "Start debugging" option in VSCode but it doesn't help me in debugging the Swift code and it seems to fail at times. 
I have tried looking at forums and posts but to no avail.

This is what my configuration (launch.json) file looks like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        }
    ]
```

}

I am not sure what is the correct setup for debugging Javascript (VSCode) and Swift (Xcode) simultaneously. Any help is appreciated.